# Add likes and page visit counts to Django project

Tags: ajax, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to give users ability to like/dislike objects (using ajax), and to count page visits. I've written functions and changed the templates but there's a mistake somewhere. The result of likes and views is always 0. It seems to me that the mistake is in views.py functions, but maybe I'm wrong, I'm a beginner in Django. Now according to the functions it is allowed for a user to like an object more then one time. I would like to let the user not to do so, but to give an ability to dislike the object. But first I would like at least a simple to  work properly. First I tried to count the number of visits of user page and to add likes for model Day.
Could you please tell me how to correct my files?

This is a part of view:

```
@login_required
def like_day(request):

    day_id = None

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'day_id' in request.GET:
            day_id = request.GET['day_id']

            likes = 0
            if day_id:
                day = Day.objects.get(id=int(day_id))
                if day:
                    likes = day.likes + 1
                    day.likes = likes
                    day.save()
            return HttpResponse(likes)

def track_url(request):
person_id = None
url = '/friends_plans/users/'
if request.method == 'GET':
    if 'person_id' in request.GET:
        person_id = request.GET['person_id']
        try:
            person = Person.objects.get(id=person_id)
            person.views = person.views + 1
            person.save()
            url = person.url
        except:
            pass

return redirect(url)
```

This are list.html (there must be a number of page views for each user)

```
{% extends 'friends_plans/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
    {% block title %} Users {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <div id ="left">
            <div id="toptitle"> Friends' Plans members:</div>
            <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Photo</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Occupation</th>
                        <th>Days</th>
                        <th>Places</th>
                        <th>Wiews</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for person in users %}
                      <tr>
                        <td><span> <img class="small_cat" src={% static 'images/cat3.jpg' %} /> </span></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'friends_plans:user' person.pk %}">{{ person.username|upper }}</a></span></td>
                        <td><span>Student at {{ person.place_of_work_or_study}}</span></td>
                        <td>{{person.day_set.all.count}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.wish_list_set.all.count}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.wish_list.comment_to_wish_list_set.all.count}}</td>
                        <td>{% if person.views >= 0 %}
                                {{person.views}} views
                                {% elif person.views == 1 %}
                                {{person.views}} view
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
            <div class="pagination">
                <div id="listing">
                    <span class="step-links">
                        {% if users.has_previous %}
                            <a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                        {% endif %}

                        <span class="current">
                            Page {{ users.number }} of {{ users.paginator.num_pages }}.
                        </span>

                        {% if users.has_next %}
                            <a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

This is day.html (there's a like button there)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html >
<head>
    <title> {{person.username}} </title>
    <meta charset ="utf -8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style_day.css' %}">
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/friends_plans-jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/friends_plans-ajax.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="container">
        <div id ="header">
            <ul id ="menu">
                <span><a href ="" >Friends' Plans</a></span>
                <span><a href ="{% url 'friends_plans:user' request.user.pk %}" >My Page</a></span>
                <span><a href ="{% url 'friends_plans:listing' %}"  >Users</a></span>
                <span><a id="helpbutton" href ="" >HELP</a></span>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id ="left">
            <div id="border">
                <div><a class="button" href="{% url 'friends_plans:user' person.pk %}">{{person.username}}</a></div>
                <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat5.jpg' %} />
            </div>
            <div id="info">
                <div class ="name"> {{person.email}} </div>
                <div class ="name"> {{person.phone_number}} </div>
                <div class ="name"> Student of {{person.place_of_work_or_study}} </div>
            </div>
            <div id="empty">  </div>

        </div>
        <div id ="right">
            <div class="sep">
                <div class="title"> {{person}}'s plans for {{day}}: </div>
                <div class="value"> Status: {{day.level_of_business}} </div>
                {% for event in day.event_set.all %}
                <div class="title1"> <a class="button" href ="">Business: {{event.business}}</a></div>
                <div class="title1"> Type: {{event.type}}</div>
                <div class="title1"> Period of time: {{event.start_time}}-{{event.end_time}}</div> <br />
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <p>
                <strong id="like_count">{{ day.likes }}</strong> users like this day
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <button id="likes" data-catid="{{day.id}}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                    Like
                </button>
                {% endif %}
            </p>
            <div>
            {% if person.id == request.user.id %}
                <a href="{% url 'friends_plans:add_event' person.pk day.pk %}">Add event</a>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id ="footer"> Copyright </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is ajax file:

```
$('#likes').click(functin()){
var catid;
catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
$.get('/friends_plans/like_day/', {day_id: catid}, function(data){
    $('#like_count').html(data);
    $('#likes').hide();
});
});
```

And these are my models, Person:

```
class Person (AbstractUser):
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
place_of_work_or_study = models.CharField(max_length=100)
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', null=True, blank=True)
url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Person'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username
```

And Day:

```
class Day(models.Model):
person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
date = models.DateField()
url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
levels = (
    ('busy', 'busy'),
    ('has_suggestions', 'has_suggestions'),
    ('waiting_for_suggestions', 'waiting_for_suggestions')
)
level_of_business = models.CharField(choices=levels, max_length=40, default='waiting_for_suggestions')
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your AJAX code is not correct. It should be

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
  var catid;
  catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
  $.get('/friends_plans/like_day/', {day_id: catid}, function(data){
      $('#like_count').html(data);
      $('#likes').hide();
  });
});
```

Furthermore, please note that you should **not** use `GET` to manipulate data on the server. This can be abused by [CSRF attacks](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Request-Forgery). Use `POST` instead.
If you choose to use `POST` you should not forget to generate a csrf-token in the template and send it together with the request either as a X-Header or inside a cookie.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it didn't help, there's still always 0 for day.likes. I think there's a mistake in my functions, because there's the same problem for count page visits, and I don't use AJAX in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem was to add `$(document).ready( function(){})`to AJAX request.